# Unable to install Canvas

Tags: canvas, discord.js

I wanted do add the canvas module to my discord.js bot, but I just get a lot of errors in the terminal, and my bot breaks.
The errors are mentioning Python, even though I use node.js

Does anyone else have this issue?
How can I fix this?

The previous errors stated that I need to download the latest version of Python, so I did

Errors from Debug log:

```
430 error code 1
431 error path C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas
432 error command failed
433 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build"
434 error Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
435 error node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
435 error node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
435 error node-pre-gyp info using node@15.0.1 | win32 | x64
435 error node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
435 error node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" (not found)
435 error node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
435 error node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
435 error node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
435 error node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.6.1 and node@15.0.1 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
435 error node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v88-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
435 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
435 error gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
435 error gyp info using node@15.0.1 | win32 | x64
435 error gyp info ok
435 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
435 error gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
435 error gyp info using node@15.0.1 | win32 | x64
435 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.0 found at "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
435 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/node-v15.0.1-headers.tar.gz
435 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/node-v15.0.1-headers.tar.gz
435 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/SHASUMS256.txt
435 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/win-x86/node.lib
435 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/win-x64/node.lib
435 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/win-arm64/node.lib
435 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/SHASUMS256.txt
435 error gyp http 404 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/win-arm64/node.lib
435 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/win-x86/node.lib
435 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/win-x64/node.lib
435 error gyp ERR! find VS
435 error gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
435 error gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
435 error gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
435 error gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
435 error gyp ERR! find VS - not found
435 error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
435 error gyp ERR! find VS
435 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
435 error gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
435 error gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
435 error gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
435 error gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
435 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
435 error gyp ERR! find VS
435 error gyp ERR! configure error
435 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:316:5)
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:327:20)
435 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1048:16)
435 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
435 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\bot\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\bot\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v88"
435 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas
435 error gyp ERR! node -v v15.0.1
435 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
435 error gyp ERR! not ok
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:327:20)
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1048:16)
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\bot\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\bot\node_modules\canvas
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.0.1
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
435 error node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
436 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the errors

Comment: Should I send the debug log or the error messages in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Share both, if you can. Right now. there's not enough information to help you. Hopefully, one of there will have some useful pointers

Comment: There is over 400 lines, how do I even share this?
EDIT: Ill just post only the lines with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was a bug at the time, I tried installing it now and it works

EDIT: My bot is failing to start now